# Mongodb query from python dictionary on all specific keys only

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have the following conf.yaml:

```
conf1: True
conf2: True
```

I have stored in my mongodb the following records:

1. `{"conf1": True, "conf2": True}`
2. `{"conf1": True, "conf2": True, "conf3": True}`

I load the conf.yaml as a dictionary in python.

Using pymongo I query:

```
import pymongo
db.collection.find(_dict)
```

The query above will return both records from the mongodb.
Instead of iterating into the results, is there any more efficient way to query checking the keys only and return a perfect match on keys and on values? (just the first record)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to filter out documents that don't have a specific field but probably It's not what you are looking for.

I doubt that there is a way to do it dynamically.

```
db.collection.find(_dict , "conf3" : { $exists: false } )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `$eq` operator in your query to match the exact key-value pairs in your dictionary. Example:

```py
import pymongo

# Load conf.yaml as a dictionary
conf_dict = {"conf1": True, "conf2": True}

# Create query using $eq operator
query = {"$eq": conf_dict}

# Query MongoDB collection
result = db.collection.find_one(query)

# Print the result
print(result)
```